Amplify gen 2 upload to S3 storage
I'm using Amplify gen 2 following the docs here:
https://docs.amplify.aws/angular/build-a-backend/storage/set-up-storage/
My storage definition:
export const storage = defineStorage({
  name: 'assets',
  access: (allow) => ({
    'images/*': [
      allow.guest.to(['read']),
      allow.authenticated.to(['write', 'read']),
      allow.groups(['Admin']).to(['write', 'read', 'delete'])
    ]
  })
});

Backend:
const backend = defineBackend({
  auth,
  data,
  storage
});

Upload code:
const result = await uploadData({
    path: `images/test.jpg`, // temp hardcode name just for testing
    data: this.imageSrc,
    options: {
      onProgress: ({ transferredBytes, totalBytes }) => {
        if (totalBytes) {
          console.log(`Upload progress ${Math.round((transferredBytes / totalBytes) * 100)} %`);
        }
      },
    },
}).result;

The bucket is created as part of my sandbox with defined permissions (see below for what is created). However, when I try to upload, I get:

Response: 403 Forbidden
Error :  AccessDenied

Note that I can get images using code such as:
const pic = await getUrl({
   path: "images/pic.jpg"
});

It's only uploading that I'm having issues.
During upload, the console.log line is hit multiple times, at 100% is when the "Access Denied" error occurs

On further investigation I noticed that the permissions assigned to the bucket relate to one principal only, and don't seem to reflect the three rules I define.
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::112233445566:role/appname-jon-CustomS3AutoDeleteObjects-SnAyMTViwDWM"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutBucketPolicy",
            "s3:GetBucket*",
            "s3:List*",
            "s3:DeleteObject*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::123456789-xmygodiybatn",
            "arn:aws:s3:::123456789-xmygodiybatn/*"
        ]
    }
]

}
Has anyone had issues with Amplify not creating the permission rules on an S3 bucket correctly?
